# Why Does V().count() Show 0 with gremlin.sh But Not Zero With Code?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

## Problem

Why does `bin/gremlin.sh`'s `V().count()` not show a non-zero count? 
I'm new to [Gremlin [Query-Language]](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/gremlin.html) and [Graph-DBs (Graph Databases)](https://www.g2.com/categories/graph-databases) in-general. 
What is the difference between running in Java-Project and the Gremlin-Console?

[image]

## Reproduction

### Steps

1. Install [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/janusgraph/janusgraph)
2. Startup [JanusGraph [Docker-container]](https://docs.janusgraph.org/getting-started/installation/) 
   `docker run -d -p 8182:8182 janusgraph/janusgraph`
3. Program-Run `g.addV()` and `g.V().count().next()` in a Java-Project
4. Command-Execute `V().count().next()` in `gremlin.sh` on the JanusGraph [Docker-container]

   ```
   docker exec -it [janusgraph.container.name] sh
   bin/gremlin.sh
   :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
   V.count()
   V.count().next()
   ```
5. Results

   1. Expect: `V().count().next()` returns would return the same value
   2. Actual: `V().count().next()` `gremlin.sh`-return returns `count=0`

```bash
$ ls
bin  conf  data  ext  lib  LICENSE.txt  logs  NOTICE.txt  scripts
$ ls bin
gremlin.bat  gremlin-server.bat  gremlin.sh  janusgraph-server.sh
$ bin/gremlin.sh

         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/janusgraph/lib/logback-classic-1.2.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/janusgraph/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
15:26:57 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
plugin activated: tinkerpop.hadoop
plugin activated: tinkerpop.spark
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
plugin activated: janusgraph.imports
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
==>Configured localhost/127.0.0.1:8182
gremlin> V().count()
==>0
gremlin> V().count().next()
==>0
gremlin> :exit
$
```

### Code

```
│   pom.xml
│
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │       Main.java
│   │   │
│   │   └───resources
│   │       │   log4j2.xml
│   │       │
│   │       ├───conf
│   │       │       remote-graph.properties
│   │       │       remote-objects.yaml
```

#### `Main.java`

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.GraphTraversalSource;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Transaction;
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Vertex;

import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;

public class Main {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        GraphTraversalSource g = traversal().withRemote("conf/remote-graph.properties");
        Transaction tx = g.tx();
        tx.open();
        g.V().drop();
//        tx.commit();
//        tx = g.tx();
        Vertex v1 = g.addV("person").property("name","marko").next();
        Vertex v2 = g.addV("person").property("name","stephen").next();
        g.V(v1).addE("knows").to(v2).property("weight",0.75).iterate();
        tx.commit();
        logger.info("g.V().count().next():\t" + g.V().count().next());
        g.close();
    }
}
```

#### `remote-graph.properties`

```
gremlin.remote.remoteConnectionClass=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.remote.DriverRemoteConnection
gremlin.remote.driver.clusterFile=src/main/resources/conf/remote-objects.yaml
gremlin.remote.driver.sourceName=g
```

#### `pom.xml`

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
            <artifactId>gremlin-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.4-20230429-020227.dc3f877</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you explicitly open a transaction, rather than let the Gremlin Server do it for you, you need to add the data to the graph within the context of that transaction using `tx.begin()`. For example (this is Python but the concepts are the same in Java)

```py
tx = g.tx()
gtx = tx.begin()

try:
    id1 = gtx.addV('tx-a1').next()
    print('Logic between transaction members')
    id2 = gtx.addV('tx-a2').next()
    tx.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    tx.rollback()
```

Comment: For Java, `gtx` doesn't have `addV`. `TraversalSource gtx = tx.begin();` rather than a `Transaction`.

Comment: It does - please see the TinkerPop test suite example here https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/6aff63cf98927866c622fff2823a7d0932c59538/gremlin-server/src/test/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/server/GremlinSessionTxIntegrateTest.java

Comment: I'll also add that if you are connecting via a Gremlin Server it should manage the transactions for you. You only really need to use explicit transactions if you want multiple Gremlin calls to be part of the same unit of work (transaction).

Comment: It at least doesn't have it with `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin-core version-3.6.2`. I can see my IntelliJ not resolving it since I'm trying it again right now. [`org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.TraversalSource`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/package-summary.html)

Comment: Intellij may be confused. `gtx` will be a `GraphTraversalSource` which absolutely has `addV` - check the definition in the example from the test suite I shared above. `GraphTraversalSource gtx = tx.begin();`

Comment: Java-Compiler does not accept that trying to run. `gtx` only resolves to `TraversalSource`, not `GraphTraversalSource`. [`default <T extends TraversalSource> T begin()`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Transaction.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253453/discussion-between-kelvin-lawrence-and-zach).